# Python regex unable to remove content between [%~ abcd ~%]

Tags: python, regex

I have raw HTML and am trying to remove this whole block like this [%~ as..abcd ~%] from the output string. Using re library of python

```
teststring = "Check the direction . [%~ MACRO wdwDate(date) BLOCK;
                 SET tmpdate = date.clone();
                 END ~%] Determine if both directions."
cleanM = re.compile('\[\%\~ .*? \~\%\]')
scleantext = re.sub(cleanM,'', teststring)
```

what is wrong in the code ?

Comment: The dot `.` doesn't match the newline character by default. You have to use the `re.DOTALL` flag. Also if you compile your pattern, the last line is : `scleantext = cleanM.sub('', teststring)`

Comment: `%`, `]`, `~` are not special characters and don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern should be

```
cleanM = re.compile(r'\[\%\~ .*? \~\%\]',re.S)
```

`.` matches any character except new line, `S` allows to match the newline

Comment: The caveat is that you need to use `re.compile` when you want to use re.S. It does not work directly in re.sub for whatever reason...

Comment: You can also exclude the markers from the match: `r'(?<=\[%~ ).*(?= \~%])'`. BTW: Always use raw strings (`r'...'`) on regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[\S\s]*` instead of `.*` and you can leave out compile:

```
import re
teststring = '''Check the direction . [%~ MACRO wdwDate(date) BLOCK;
                 SET tmpdate = date.clone();
                 END ~%] Determine if both directions.'''
scleantext = re.sub('(\[%~ [\S\s]* ~%\])', '', teststring)

print(scleantext)
```